# How to Implementing Direct eSIM Installation from Web Browser Instead of QR Code Scanning

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on adding a feature to install eSIM profiles directly from a web app. Traditionally, eSIM installation processes are carried out through mobile apps. For instance, here's the procedure for Android:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview

On web platforms, the common method involves using a QR code. A user scans this code with their mobile device to initiate the eSIM installation, as illustrated below:
[image]

However, this method is not very user-friendly. Often, users have to take a picture of the QR code using another person's device and then scan it from that saved image.

Given that a QR code is essentially an encoded string, and seeing its structure from the image provided, I attempted to embed the same code into a URL. Unfortunately, when I clicked on this URL from my mobile device, it did not produce the same result as scanning the QR code. It seems the mobile OS handles QR code scans differently from directly accessed URLs in a browser.

How can I facilitate eSIM installation directly from the web? Alternatively, is there a way to prompt the mobile OS to process the eSIM code from a web browser in the same manner it would from a QR code scan?
I am open to any way using web technology (js , php , api ... whatever)

Comment: I'd be keen to hear of any answers to this question.